# How to compile a C++ DLL using Marshal class

Tags: dll, c++-cli

I just started working with C++ yesterday and I'm stuck on what I suspect is a trivial problem.  The main DLL class is generating **error C2653: 'Marshal': is not a class or namespace name**.

I'm pretty sure I've copied the syntax almost verbatim from the MSDN page on using this class.  Here is the code:

```
// VideoInfoAssembly.cpp
// compile with: /clr

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "VideoInfoAssembly.h"

#pragma managed

namespace VideoInfoAssembly
{
    short VideoInfo::GetWidth(System::String^ managedString)
    {
        // Marshal the managed string to unmanaged memory. 
        char* stringPointer = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString).ToPointer();

        // Always free the unmanaged string.
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(stringPointer));

        return 9001;
    }
}
```

At a high level, I have a C# app that needs to read the video properties of video files and the Microsoft Media Foundation requires C++.  I've successfully built the DLL and had it return over 9000 as a test.  Now, I'm trying to pass a managed string to the DLL (which will be video file name); however, I've been struggling for over an hour to get the Marshal class to function.  As stated earlier, I've been using the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) page without success.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem induced by pre-compiled headers.  The compiler will skip everything until it finds the #include for the precompiled header file.  The mistake you made is not putting `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of the file.  So fix it like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"             // Has to be first
#include "VideoInfoAssembly.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

// etc..
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple.